# unique key durante período de tempo

Tags: mysql

A minha tabela é constituída da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE `AgendaVisitas` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `respons` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DataRegisto` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `colaborador` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Eu preciso que a coluna `title` seja `unique key` durante 7 dias.

Exemplo:

A semana começa à segunda e termina a domingo. Se registar o código 525 na coluna `title` na terça-feira desta semana, só poderei voltar a registar o mesmo código na semana seguinte, depois de domingo. Pretendo esta ação todas as semanas. só posso registar o mesmo código uma vez por semana.

Como posso fazer esta ação?

Comment: Estou longe de ser o melhor com banco de dados, mas nesse caso fazer esse tipo de verificação pelo _back-end_ não seria suficiente? :]

Comment: Outra possível solução é com o uso de triggers no próprio banco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o que você quer é que, para cada nova linha, ocorra uma contagem de 1 semana:

- Crie campos para titulo, semana e ano.
- Configure uma chave única envolvendo os 3 campos.

Cada semana tem um número único no ano e, para obter esse número, você pode utilizar a função WEEK do MySQL.

---

Se o que você quer é alterar a estrutura da tabela periodicamente, você pode criar um evento no MySql. [Aqui tem um tutorial explicando](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/).

A sintaxe é basicamente a seguinte:

```
CREATE EVENT youreventname
    ON SCHEDULE AT yourtime
    DO yourinstructions
```

Comment: ok isso é mesmo o que pretendo. O meu problema é fazer com que o evento verifique entre segunda e domingo, no momento em que for registado, mesmo sendo registado à sexta e que chegue a segunda feira seguinte e volte a verificar a semana seguinte dentro desse intervalo. Não sei se me fiz entender.

Comment: Analisando melhor, parece que a minha resposta não serve para o seu problema. Se o que você quer é que, para cada nova linha, ocorra uma contagem de 1 semana, eu sugiro que crie um campo para a semana (`week`), e crie a chave única com os campos `title` e `week`. No campo `week` você guardaria o número correspondente àquela semana no ano. Você pode usar a função WEEK do MySQL https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php

Comment: A uk deve ter tittle,week e year , pois as semanas se repetem ao longo dos anos , só semana e title daria chance de colisão

Comment: @Jp Rodrigues obrigado, era mesmo isso que pretendia

Comment: Valeu! Editei a resposta pra combinar melhor com a pergunta.